# gdalWarp : Assigning more than one nodata value

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, gdalwarp

I am working with a single band raster file in pyQgis and want to assign multiple Nodata values while reprojecting. I tried doing this but it took only the first value 32761 as Nodata value:

```
gdal.Warp(outputRaster,rlayer,dstSRS='EPSG:4326',dstNodata="32761 32762 32763 32764 32765 32766 32767")
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that. According to the doc https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-dstnodata, you can have different values in dstNodata for each band in case you have more bands

Answer (score 2):

Use the Raster Calculator to replace anything above 32760 with 32767. Then set 32767 as the nodata value. The expression in the calculator would be:

```
(raster1>32760)*32767+(raster1<32761)*raster1
```

which will either be the value of the raster or 32767, depending on whether it is greater than 32760.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible to assign one nodata value per band with GDAL. QGIS has it's own mechanism for recording a list of additional nodata values (Properties - Transparency - Custom Transparency Options). I suppose that it is possible to do the same with pyqgis but that must be done in a separate operation after gdal.Warp.

Even assigning different nodata values for each band with GDAL is not simple. Gdalwarp and warp Python method offer this option but for example gdal_translate does not. The gdalwarp option is documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html as

> -dstnodata <value [value...]>
>
> Set nodata values for output bands (different values can be supplied
> for each band). If more than one value is supplied all values should
> be quoted to keep them together as a single operating system argument.
> New files will be initialized to this value and if possible the nodata
> value will be recorded in the output file. Use a value of None to
> ensure that nodata is not defined. If this argument is not used then
> nodata values will be copied from the source dataset.

What is not directly documented is that only few raster formats support different nodata values for bands. GDAL Virtual format is one of those formats but the very common GIS image format TIFF/GeoTIFF is not.

From the TIFF specification https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/gdal_nodata.html:

> Description
>
> Used by the GDAL library, contains an ASCII encoded nodata
> or background pixel value.
>
> In the geospatial image processing field especially (and in other
> fields) it is common to use a special pixel value to mark geospatial
> areas for which no information is available. This is often called a
> "nodata" or "background" value. Applications often treat these pixels
> as transparent and they are often not included in spatial statistics
> for the image. Non-geospatial applications might still use the nodata
> value to track a special value that should be treated as transparent
> since currently TIFF palettes don't include an alpha value.
>
> The GDAL_NODATA tag is intended to keep track of what pixel value is
> being used for this background nodata value. It is ASCII encoded so
> that if the pixel value 255 was to be treated as nodata, then the tag
> would have the value "255".
>
> If this tag is absent there is assume to be no nodata value in effect
> for the image. If the image has more than one sample it is assumed
> that all samples have the same nodata value.
>
> This tag is currently only supported by the GDAL library.